# php login on ext. jsp webpage using curl

Tags: php, jsp, curl

L.S.

I have some development skills but I am new to php curl.
I`m trying to create a php script that logins in the intraship page whitout any user interaction.

I have used fiddler to determine the values that are posted and searched the login form for hidden values.

One loading the login page the jsessionid and a unique RRP number are generated and posted on submit.

I have create the script below that collects the unique numbers from the login page and submits the data but it's only showing me the login page...
Could somebody please help me out and tell me what I am missing.

```
<?php
//set var
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "www.intraship-dhl.nl/intraship/jsp/SessionCtrl.jsp";
$jTFName = "foobar";
$jPFPassword = "foo";
$jCBLanguage = "NL";
$jsstate = "false";
$jCBLanguage = "NL";
$jBtnSendLogin = "1";
$cookie = "C:/wamp/www/dhl.txt";

//start with curl
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.15"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $output;

//start processing output to determine jsessionid, URL and RRP
$jsessionid_sub = array();
$var1 = preg_match('/jsessionid=(.*?)\?/s', $output, $jsessionid_sub);
$jsessionid = ($jsessionid_sub[1]);
//print_r($jsessionid_sub[1]);
$URL_sub = array ();
$var2 = preg_match('/URL=(.*?)\&/s', $output, $URL_sub);
$URL = ($URL_sub[1]);
//print_r($URL_sub[1]);
$RRP_sub = array();
$var3 = preg_match('/RRP=(.*?)\"/s', $output, $RRP_sub);
$RRP = ($RRP_sub[1]);
//print_r($RRP_sub[1]);

//continue post the data and collect the result page 

$postdata = "jBtnSendLogin=1&jBtnOK=Login&jTFName=".$jTFName."&jPFPassword=".$jPFPassword."&jsessionid=".$jsessionid."&RRP=".$RRP."&URL=".$URL."&jsstate=".$jsstate."&jCBLanguage=".$jCBLanguage."&jBtnSendLogin=".$jBtnSendLogin."&jBtnRefreshPage=1";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell the case, but I notice in second call you are posting session id as post data, which I am pretty sure is not the case, no website took session id as post data, they usually goes in HTML request header. you are using fiddler determine correctly what session and cookie values are been posted and what are part of request header and I am sure it will work fine once you have correct values.

Comment: Hey Sumit, the post action of the form =
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/intraship/jsp/LoginCtrl.jsp;jsessionid=88A79079261879DE8A20CC78A56FB224.node_08?URL=LoginDlg2.jsp&RRP=P88uiEZ56eN2" class="tabFont00" target="_top">

Comment: see that means jsessionid is not part of POST DATA, it is part of URL to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `curl_close` after the first request, otherwise curl will not save the cookie into the file. That's why you are getting the login page again and again!

```
curl_close($ch);
```

Now open a new curl session for the second POST:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
// and the other options you might add from previous request, just add here!
```

This should work for you.

Comment: @user3187831 if you already tried the suggestion i posted, then please update your code in description. "Tried, and didnt work" type of response will not help you to get an answer! You have to provide as much info as possible, if you really want to have an answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK after doing some more research i have the following code only it is generating an empty page.

Could somebody tell me what i`m missing?

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url="http://www.intraship-dhl.nl/intraship/jsp/SessionCtrl.jsp";
$cookie = "C:/wamp/www/cookie.txt";

curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.15',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $output;

$post_sub = array();
$var1 = preg_match('/LoginCtrl.jsp;(.*?)\" class/s', $output, $post_sub);
$post = ($post_sub[1]);

$jTFName = "foobar";
$jPFPassword = "foo";
$jsstate = "true";
$jCBLanguage = "NL";
$jBtnSendLogin = "1";
$postData = "jsstate=".$jsstate."&jTFName=".$jTFName."&jPFPassword=".$jPFPassword."&jCBLanguage=".$jCBLanguage."&jBtnSendLogin=".$jBtnSendLogin;
$url2 = $url.$post;
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $c, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => $url2,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.15',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_POST => true
));
$result = curl_exec($c);
echo $result;

?>
```